# No route to host при пробросе портов

Tags: сеть, ssh, порт

Сеть такая:

```
A.A.A.A ---- C.C.C.C --- WAN ---- D.D.D.D ---- E.E.E.E
```

A - Raspberry Pi, которая имеет локальный IP-адрес A.A.A.A.

C - роутер NAG SNR, который имеет публичный динамический адрес C.C.C.C.

D - роутер, который имеет публичный динамический адрес D.D.D.D.

E - компьютер, который имеет локальный IP-адрес E.E.E.E.

На А поднят SSH-сервер на порту 22. На C настроен проброс портов TCP и UDP с 22 на 22 на адрес A.A.A.A.

Я работаю на компьютере E, с которого пытаюсь подключиться к Raspberry. Сначала проверяю связь с роутером:

```
$ ping C.C.C.C
PING C.C.C.C (C.C.C.C) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from C.C.C.C: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=201 ms
64 bytes from C.C.C.C: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=199 ms
```

Связь имеется. Далее выполняю подключение по SSH:

```
$ ssh pi@C.C.C.C
pi@C.C.C.C's password: 
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v7+ #1642 SMP Mon Apr  3 17:20:52 BST 2023 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Sep 27 20:26:14 2023 from 192.168.1.176
```

Первое подключение прошло успешно. Но при каждом последующем получается такая ошибка:

```
$ ssh pi@C.C.C.C
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.103 port 22: No route to host
```

Указанный адрес не принадлежит сети роутера D. Адрес принадлежит сети роутера C, но не используется (то есть он есть в доступном диапазоне адресов, но не назначен ни одному узлу). Я делаю вывод, что это именно роутер C пытается перенаправить запросы на узел 192.168.1.103 вместо узла A.A.A.A, то есть правило проброса работает неправильно. Верно ли это? И что делать дальше? Как добиться подключения?

Comment: перед ошибкой что написано?

Comment: Сообщение "No route to host" означает следующее: в моей таблице маршрутизации нет маршрута в подсеть узла назначения.

Comment: @Akina, разумеется. Раз узел такой отсутствует, то и маршрут к нему отсутствует. Вот только почему он присутствует в выводе?

Comment: @eri, ничего, только команда подключения. Если эта команда имеет ключи и параметры, с помощью которых можно получить больше информации об ошибке, то напишите.

Comment: Какая команда подключения?

Comment: *Раз узел такой отсутствует, то и маршрут к нему отсутствует.* Не-не. Не к самому узлу, а к подсети, в которой он лежит. Если бы маршрут был, а узла не было, было бы Timeout. PS. Такое сообщение может прийти не только от локального интерфейса, но и от какого-то промежуточного узла.

Comment: @eri, я обновил вопрос, добавил команду.

Comment: @Akina, но ведь адреса вида 192.168.Х.Х зарезервированы для локальных сетей. То есть это может быть сеть одного из роутеров. Это точно не роутер D: у него сеть 192.168.31.0/24Но, получается, что и не роутер C: сеть у него 192.168.1.0/24, но он не может возвращать ошибку, ведь у него точно есть маршрут, раз это его сеть. А можно ли как-то определить, какой именно узел вернул эту ошибку? Ping до роутера C работает всегда.

Comment: *можно ли как-то определить, какой именно узел вернул эту ошибку* Странно, что эта информация не указывается - я как-то привык к сообщениям типа "Node XXX claims: no route to host YYY".. *Ping до роутера C работает всегда* Если роутер - в сети 192.168.1.0/24, и пинг именно по адресу из этой сети проходит всегда, то скорее всего именно роутер и возвращает ошибку... можно попробовать перехватить и самостоятельно распарсить ICMP-пакет с ошибкой.

Comment: @Akina, нет, у меня таких сообщений нет. Я использую `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`. С проблемой я разобрался. Когда я настраивал VS Code на подключение к удалённому узлу, я случайно испортил файл `~/.ssh/config`. Из-за этого терминал пытался подключиться не к тому узлу, который задан в командной строке. Если вы знаете смысл параметров `Host`, `HostName` этого файла, то можете оформить ответ. Или я могу сделать это через некоторое время, когда разберусь.